# Change [feature-request] to [característica-nueva]

Tags: petición-de-funcionalidad, estado-completado, reetiquetado

Look at our required tags:

- [soporte](/questions/tagged/soporte)
- [discusión](/questions/tagged/discusi%c3%b3n)
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)
- [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

All have Spanish names, except for [feature-request](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) (and bug, which I don't think has a good Spanish equivalent). Looking at [Spanish Stack Overflow, they have `característica-nueva`](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/caracter%c3%adstica-nueva). **Could we change this (but leave [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) as a synonym)?**

---

Miren nuestras etiquetas necesarias:

- [soporte](/questions/tagged/soporte)
- [discusión](/questions/tagged/discusi%c3%b3n)
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)
- [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Todas tienen nombres en español, excepto [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) (y [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), pero no creo que tenga una buena traducción). [Stack Overflow en español tiene `característica-nueva`](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/caracter%c3%adstica-nueva). **¿Podríamos cambiar esto (pero dejando [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) como sinónimo)?**

<sub>feel free to correct my Spanish, I'm learning :-)</sub>

Comment: Me parece bastante razonable. @walen y los que vengan detrás, proponed en respuestas vuestras opciones y la más votada la ponemos como etiqueta definitiva (estableciendo la antigua en inglés como sinónimo). Daremos como plazo una semana.

Comment: @walen pero creo que debe ser consistente con Stack Overflow en Español.

Comment: @walen why'd you change it to tenga instead of tiene? I'm not sure how the subjunctive is better there, but then again I'm not experienced at Spanish.

Comment: Hay unas etiquetas por defecto en todo Meta: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/63019/209901 En Meta SOes publicamos la lista y las tradujimos en [Traduzcamos toda la lista de etiquetas predeterminadas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1887/83). Aquí empecé a traducir unas cuantas, pero [un bug](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3495/83) me hizo desistir para no liar. Parece que está corregido, si bien no lo he comprobado (ya lo reportaron como resuelto previamente).

Comment: This is live now. The tag is now [meta-tag:petición-de-funcionalidad]

Answer (score 3):

Me parece una propuesta lógica. Todas las etiquetas del sitio principal están en español. También es cierto que muchas de las de Meta no lo están ([moderation](/questions/tagged/moderation), [editing](/questions/tagged/editing), [on-topic-definition](/questions/tagged/on-topic-definition), [scope](/questions/tagged/scope)...), pero bueno, muchas otras sí y no veo problema en que lo estén todas.

---

Seems logical. All of the tags on the main site are translated to Spanish. It's also true that many of the Meta ones are not (see above) but then again a lot of them are, and I don't see a problem in translating them all.

---

Sinónimos propuestos // Proposed synonyms:

- *`bug`* → `fallo`
- *`feature-request`* → `petición-de-cambio` / `petición-de-funcionalidad`

---

Comment: Me gusta *petición-de-funcionalidad*.  Quizás sería opción también *funcionialidad-propuesta*.  O *propuesta-de-funcionalidad*.

Comment: Me quedo con [meta-tag:petición-de-funcionalidad], por ser más amplia que "cambio". A veces nos referimos a cambiar algo, pero en muchas ocasiones las _feature request_ piden nuevas cosas que creo que están bien traducidas como _funcionalidades_.